# ASP Net Core call Azure B2C policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I've spent a couple of days to figure out on how to properly call Azure B2C policy/user flows from ASP Net core.
We are able to call B2C sign in and sign up custom policy.

We have implemented the same approach for Change Password and other custom policies created.
However, when we call other custom policies(not included in the code below but same implementation), we encountered different errors.
New errors are coming up whenever we fix the error.

This leads me think that we are not doing the proper way to call B2C custom polcies/user flows.
May I know if the code below are correct or maybe you can suggest a better way to do it.

Thank you.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => HostingEnvironment.IsProduction();
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("B2C_1A_SignIn", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["B2C_1A_SignIn:Domain"]}";
            options.MetadataAddress = $"https://{Configuration["B2C_1A_SignIn:MetadataAddress"]}";

            // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
            options.ClientId = Configuration["B2C_1A_SignIn:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["B2C_1A_SignIn:ClientSecret"];

            // Set response type to code
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;

            // Configure the scope
            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");

            // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:3000/callback
            // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Home");

            // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
            options.ClaimsIssuer = "B2C_1A_SignIn";

            // Saves tokens to the AuthenticationProperties
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("B2C_1A_ChangePassword", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["B2C_1A_ChangePassword:Domain"]}";
            options.MetadataAddress = $"https://{Configuration["B2C_1A_ChangePassword:MetadataAddress"]}";
            options.ClientId = Configuration["B2C_1A_ChangePassword:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["B2C_1A_ChangePassword:ClientSecret"];
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
            options.Scope.Clear();
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Home");
            options.ClaimsIssuer = "B2C_1A_ChangePassword";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        })
        );
    }
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    public async Task SignIn()
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("B2C_1A_SignIn", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/home" });
    }

    [Authorize]
    public async Task ChangePassword()
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("B2C_1A_ChangePassword", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/home" });
    }
```

Comment: Your callback paths probably need to be changed at least. They are usually set to URLs that don't match pages in the app. The auth scheme will redirect you there anyway. Specify callback paths like `/signin-callback` and `/change-pw-callback`.

Comment: I change the callback to /signin-callback and registered in the Azure tenant as Reply URL (https://localhost:44339/signin-callback), it did not work. I know that this reply URL will be called once the authentication has been completed, however, I don't understand why it's not formatted to controller/action. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Because that URL doesn't have to match an action. The authentication middleware should handle it.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Your suggestion solved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: hi @user1805220 what is the code required in chang-pw-callback .In my case, it returned back from b2c instead of showing the change password screen. All i wanted was to skip the enter username password screen when the user is already logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback paths probably need to be changed at least. Specify callback paths like `/signin-callback` and `/change-pw-callback`.

They don't need to match actions in your app. The authentication schemes will usually issue a "local redirect" to the URL you specified (or the current URL) after you are redirected back to your app.

Comment: Thanks for saving my sanity, mate